# C++ Stack around a variable is corrupted

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, runtime

I'm getting the following error from the code I've written - 
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pChar' was corrupted

From research it is suggestive that the problem has to do with pHexValueBuffer = new char[256] and the memset and how I'm using the veritable - to store values to return a Hex number instead of Decimal. My research suggests that somehow I'm going out of bounds with the memory I've set, just not understanding the how.

Any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

```
void DecToHex()
{
    string input;
    int total = 0;
    int index = 254;
    char pChar;
    char* pHexValueBuffer = new char[256];
    memset(pHexValueBuffer, 0, 256 );
    pHexValueBuffer[255] = '\0';

    cout << "Enter a Decimal Number\n\n" << flush;

    cin >> input;
    unsigned int iValue = atoi(input.c_str());


    do
    {
        --index;
        unsigned int iMod = iValue % 16;
        if( iMod > 9 )
        {
            switch (iMod)
            {
            case 10:
                pHexValueBuffer[index] = 'A';
                break;
            case 11:
                pHexValueBuffer[index] = 'B';
                break;
            case 12:
                pHexValueBuffer[index] = 'C';
                break;
            case 13:
                pHexValueBuffer[index] = 'D';
                break;
            case 14:
                pHexValueBuffer[index] = 'E';
                break;
            case 15:
                pHexValueBuffer[index] = 'F';
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            itoa(iMod, &pChar, 10 );
            pHexValueBuffer[index] = pChar;
        }
        iValue = iValue/16;

    } while( iValue > 0 );

    cout << "Decimal Number = " << &pHexValueBuffer[index];
    delete []pHexValueBuffer;
    pHexValueBuffer = NULL;
}
```

Comment: A really easy way to figure it out is to use bound-checked iterators instead of pointers (e.g. to a vector instead of an array) and see where they give you errors. Or if you don't have those, use vector::at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here

```
char pChar;

itoa(iMod, &pChar, 10 );
```

itoa works with an array of chars not a single one.

You can find examples of how to use `itoa` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/).

Also if you are anyway going to be using `itoa`, you can avoid the whole `DecToHex()` function & just call `itoa`

```
int val;
char pHexValueBuffer[256]
cout << "Enter a Decimal Number\n\n" << flush;
cin >> val;
itoa(val, pHexValueBuffer, 16);
cout << "Hexadecimal Number = " << pHexValueBuffer;
```

And you are done.

Comment: the DecToHex() function is because this program is for converting to other base numbers also. its mostly to separate them out so i don't end up running code that I'm not testing. for example I have working binarytoDec() and dectobinary() written so far.

Comment: `itoa` can convert to other base numbers also - check the 3rd parameter.

Comment: ...oh wow... that.. changes how I write the code, darn no wonder the teach said it should only take me a copple of hours to write this... (Current time taken so far 2+ days aprox)

Comment: Now just to reverse the process. :)

Thank you greatly :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the call to itoa

```
itoa(iMod, &pChar, 10 );
```

itoa will put a null char at the end - so you need to pass an array of 2 chars. try

```
char pChar[2];

...
itoa(iMod,pChar,10);
```

With your code itoa call would have ended up writing to index variable.